# how to schedule report or dashboard as different user?

Tags: email, dashboard, custom-reports, schedule

I have a lightning community with two profiles types.

Managers and Promoters.

I need a way to email schedule reports or dashboards to the managers with the informacion of its own promoters.

it is possible to login as all my managers (13 in total) create a report for each one, and schedule for each one?

Comment: it is possible to login as all my managers (13 in total) create a report for each one, and schedule for each one?

Comment: @TomasGarciaEtchegaray, yes, if you do it by hand.

Comment: thanks! I wiil do it

Comment: @DavidReed Create reports isnt available in lighning communities =(, so i cant login as a manager and create and schedule the report.

Comment: Also its not possible to create a report with Running user as a Partner Community User